# Is it possible to dynamically import data into Jira from XML?

Tags: xml, import, jira

I am planning on setting up a XML repository which will be dynamically polled by JIRA for updating stories.
The workflow would be :

1. Export requirement to a XML
2. Place the XML in a directory
3. JIRA application needs to poll that directory regularly and check for changes
4. Update the tickets in JIRA based on the changes

Using Adobe Framemaker to export requirements to XML but I am stuck at the importing part. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

You have some options here:

1. Convert the XML to a CSV (maybe with XSL) and use the CSV importer
   https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/importing-data-from-csv-185729516.html
2. Have a simple script that reads the XML and parses the info, and then use the Jira REST api to import the data
   https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

Also, in 2015 I would use JSON instead of XML ;)